# How to set display:none for responsive mobile view?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a responsive website. For mobile view, I want to hide the right banner div from sample code below so I just write'display: none;' but the container div came up and overlay with the row div. I just want to hide the right banner without any affect alignment of other divs. Could you please help me if I can sets height for row div or any other issues?

```html
 

    <div class="row clearfix">
 <div class="left-banner">
     <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="right-banner">
     <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <p></p>
</div>
```

```css
.row{width:100%;}
.left-banner{float:left; width:60%;}
.right-banner{float:right; width:40%; display:none;}
.container{width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media query.

```
@media (max-width: <desired width of viewport>) {
   .right-banner{
      display:none;
   }
}
```

Media query is use to adjust your design according to desired viewport.

have a read- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

**EDIT**

You can try to use visibility:hidden on your right-banner instead of display:none, this way even if its hidden the space will still remain as if the right-banner is still there.

Comment: Nope, I didn't saw your answer when I was editing. I just realized after submiting the edit form,

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try media queries ?

```
@media all and (max-width: 658px) { // for mobile 

.right-banner{

    float:right; width:40%; display:none;

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, once I did this, the right-banner hides in mobile view but the container div came up and collapse with row div. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes, once you make your right banner div invisible, the elements after it comes up, and takes its place, not letting it be empty, you can use media queries again, to allocate and align elements the way you want them to appear, or you can try visbility:hidden if you don't want elements to collapse, it keeps the element's placeholder for you....

Answer (score 0):

You should use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none` so that other elements' position is not affected.

Comment: I tried visibility: hidden; it not affected any other divs but it displays the blank white space in that area.

Comment: @RazikCib so what do you want to do with that blank space? what you want to appear at that space??

Answer (score 0):

You have only to declare in the div-container `float: left`, than your code will work :)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/yztgv595/1/)

```
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="right-banner">
    <img src="http://im1.book.com.tw/image/getImage?i=http://www.books.com.tw/img/001/061/38/0010613865.jpg&w=348&h=348" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="left-banner">
    <img src="http://im1.book.com.tw/image/getImage?i=http://www.books.com.tw/img/001/061/38/0010613865.jpg&w=348&h=348" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Here is the css part:

```
.row{width:100%;}
.left-banner{width:50%;float:left;}
.right-banner{width:50%;float:right;display:none;}
.container{width:100%;float:left;}
```

Comment: For the future it's better to use CSS media queries.